# How do you list ALL packages in Nuget

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to list all packages available through the NuGet command line interface.

When I use the following command:

Get-Package -Remote

In the package manager console, it only lists the first 100 packages.

Thank you

Eric

Answer (score 38):

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable
```

or

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter NHibernate
```

Comment: The `PageSize` and `Skip` arguments are very helpful as well. ex: `Get-Package -ListAvailable -PageSize 100 -Skip 200`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-get-package

Answer (score 9):

We enabled server side paging on the odata feed which has a page limit of 100. We've fixed the client in the next version of NuGet to get all packages even with the server limit. More info here http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/510

Comment: You can try running 1.1 by installing it from http://ci.nuget.org:8080/guestAuth/repository/download/bt4/.lastSuccessful/VisualStudioAddIn/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Answer (score 2):

List-Package -Remote | Out-GridView